# Correct way to use JSDoc with anonymous object and functions of this object

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget, webstorm, jsdoc

Currently using Webstorm in a project with Dojo (1.10), and ESRI API Javascript.

I have a function that accept a Widget (Object/Class), but the Webstorm show me some warnings because of JSDoc.

Code:

```
/**
 * Init toolbar
 *
 * @param {Object} [options] - Toolbar options
 * @param {string} [options.title=Default title] - Main title
 * @param {ToolbarWidget} toolbarObj - Toolbar widget to set
 */
initToolbar: function(options, toolbarObj) {
  ...
  toolbarObj.set('title', _title);
}
```

The first warning was on '**toolbarObj**'. I get a message '*Unresolved variable or type*'.

This was easy to resolve. Just included the following JSDoc:

```
/**
 * A dojo widget (toolbar).
 * @typedef {Object} ToolbarWidget
 */
```

Now, the another warning was the '**set**' function of toolbarObj.
I get a warning with the following message: '*unresolved function or method set()*'.

Already tried @name, @function (maybe not in the correct way)!

I known this is optional (is just a warning), but, I like to document everything in the right way.
So, how I can document the 'set' function of a anonymous object/dojo widget?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
/**
 * A dojo widget (toolbar).
 * @typedef  {Object} ToolbarWidget
 * @property {function} set 
 */
```